# How to get full json data from REST API via ARC

Tags: java, rest, http

I am trying to hit RESTFUL API through arc to get a response as full JSON data. But sometimes in the response some JSON data missing which means getting half JSON data.

What is the issue?

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Expected Json data is `{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": [
        { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
        { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
    ]
 }` but I' am getting response like this `{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": [
        { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
        { "name":"Fiat",`  half of the json data missing in response.

Comment: Assuming you are reading the full response, Should you contact the API administrator rather than us?